# Hamburger navbar activation problems?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a basic hamburger icon navbar built with CSS but am unable to activate the navbar properly when I click anywhere on the outside of the nav it activates the animation for the whole nav does anyone know why this could be I have tried searching around StackOverflow and google but cannot seem to find my answer?

```js
// Mobile Nav
document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (
    e.target.matches(".menu-btn") ||
    e.target.matches(".btn-line") ||
    e.target.matches(".activate-nav")
  ) {
    toggleMenu();
  }
});

function toggleMenu() {
  document.querySelector(".mobile-content").classList.toggle("hide");
}

// Hamburger Animation
$(".mobile-nav").click(function() {
  $(".btn-line").toggleClass("close");
});
```

```css
.mobile-nav {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

h2 {
  padding: 0.6rem;
}

.menu-btn {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

.btn-line {
  width: 28px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 0 0 4px 0;
  background: #333;
  z-index: 3;
  border-radius: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}


/*  Animation start  */

.btn-line.close:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
  background: blue;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.btn-line.close:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-45deg);
  background: blue;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.mobile-content {
  background: #333;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.mobile-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80vh;
}

.mobile-items {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Mobile Nav -->
<div class="mobile-nav">
  <a href="#home">
    <h2>MATTY</h2>
  </a>
  <div class="menu-btn">
    <div class="btn-line"></div>
    <div class="btn-line"></div>
  </div>
  <nav class="mobile-content hide">
    <ul class="mobile-item">
      <li class="mobile-items">
        <a href="#about-me" class="mobile-link activate-nav">
               ABOUT
             </a>
      </li>
      <li class="mobile-items">
        <a href="#the-portfolio" class="mobile-link activate-nav">
               PORTFOLIO
             </a>
      </li>
      <li class="mobile-items">
        <a href="#home" class="mobile-link activate-nav">
          <del>BLOG</del>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="mobile-items">
        <a href="#contact-me" class="mobile-link activate-nav">
               CONTACT
             </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Your problem is that, when You click on 'Matty' animation starts ? If yes is because You have 'click' event on 'mobile-nav' class which is wrapping whole navbar.

Comment: When I click on Matty the animation starts on the hamburger and when I click on the line of the nav it goes back to the home page and would like it to just go to the homepage when just matty is clicked here is my website below so u can get a live example of what I mean btw you will have to view in mobile view any help really appreciated! https://www.mattyburton.com/

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of this code

```
// Hamburger Animation
$(".mobile-nav").click(function() {
  $(".btn-line").toggleClass("close");
});
```

make it ie: replace mobile-nav

```
$(".menu-btn").click(function() {
      $(".btn-line").toggleClass("close");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So maybe try replace:

`// Hamburger Animation
$(".mobile-nav").click(function() {
  $(".btn-line").toggleClass("close");
});`

to:

`$("body").on('click', '.menu-btn', function() {
  $(".btn-line").toggleClass("close");
});`

Answer (score 0):

I just update few script in your code, try this i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

You actually calling 2 click methods when user click on **hamburger** menu. That's not good practice we need to merge both methods in 1 method.

```
document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (e.target.matches(".menu-btn") ||  e.target.matches(".activate-nav")
  ) {
    if(e.target.matches(".menu-btn")){
      $(".btn-line").toggleClass("close");
    }
    toggleMenu();
  }
});
```

Remove `e.target.matches(".btn-line")` from **if statement** you already checking his parent class in **if statement** no need to check child class.

Also remove below jquery code, we don't need it any more.

```
// Hamburger Animation
$(".mobile-nav").click(function() {
  $(".btn-line").toggleClass("close");
});
```

```js
// Mobile Nav
document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (e.target.matches(".menu-btn") ||  e.target.matches(".activate-nav")
  ) {
    if(e.target.matches(".menu-btn")){
      $(".btn-line").toggleClass("close");
    }
    toggleMenu();
  }
});

function toggleMenu() {
  document.querySelector(".mobile-content").classList.toggle("hide");
}
```

```css
.mobile-nav {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

h2 {
  padding: 0.6rem;
}

.menu-btn {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  right: 20px;
  top: 14px;
  padding: 6px 0;
}

.btn-line {
  width: 28px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 0 0 4px 0;
  background: #333;
  z-index: 3;
  border-radius: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}


/*  Animation start  */

.btn-line.close:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
  background: blue;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.btn-line.close:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-45deg);
  background: blue;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.mobile-content {
  background: #333;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.mobile-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80vh;
}

.mobile-items {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.mobile-nav > a {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Mobile Nav -->
<div class="mobile-nav">
  <a href="#home">
    <h2>MATTY</h2>
  </a>
  <div class="menu-btn">
    <div class="btn-line"></div>
    <div class="btn-line"></div>
  </div>
  <nav class="mobile-content hide">
    <ul class="mobile-item">
      <li class="mobile-items">
        <a href="#about-me" class="mobile-link activate-nav">
               ABOUT
             </a>
      </li>
      <li class="mobile-items">
        <a href="#the-portfolio" class="mobile-link activate-nav">
               PORTFOLIO
             </a>
      </li>
      <li class="mobile-items">
        <a href="#home" class="mobile-link activate-nav">
          <del>BLOG</del>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="mobile-items">
        <a href="#contact-me" class="mobile-link activate-nav">
               CONTACT
             </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Added it to my website and still, no luck here is a link to my site so it explains the problem more u will need to go into mobile view to show the hamburger nav https://www.mattyburton.com/

Comment: It's working fine hit `ctrl+f5` and try again. Thanks

Comment: But when you click the center of the navbar it activates the navbar and goes back to the homepage?

Comment: Are you move my Javascript changes ? I still see your old script in `main.js`.

Comment: The header logo anchor it's actually contain full header with. I just updated few CSS rest of things are good update CSS will resolve your issue. Thanks

Comment: Tried adding still no luck and the nav hamburger doesn't close the x when i click of it now aswell

Comment: Have you deploy my **CSS** changes ?

Comment: I didn't deploy the changes but I changed it on my laptop and still no luck unsure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please deploy If it's possible for more clarification. Thanks

Comment: i have deployed it btw

Comment: That's strange I updated the branch on GitHub and its showing my changes on GitHub but not on my site